# Django doesn't run all unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am following the django tutorial about unit tests at tangowithdjango.com.

I have my code like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from rango.models import Category

class CategoryMethodTests(TestCase):

    def test_ensure_views_are_positive(self):

        """
        ensure_views_are_positive
        should results True for
        categories where views
        are zero or positive
        """
        cat = Category(name='test',views=-1, likes=0)
        cat.save()
        self.assertEqual((cat.views >= 0), True)

    def test_slug_line_creation(self):
        """
        slug_line_creation checks
        to make sure that when we
        add a category an appropriate
        slug line is created

        i.e. "Random Category String"
                ->
             "random-category-string"
        """

        cat = Category(name='Random Category String')
        cat.save()
        self.assertEqual(cat.slug, 'random-category-string')
```

when I run

```
python manage.py test rango
```

It works fine but it says 1 tests run when in fact I have two
Also when I write a failing test in the second test, it doesn't throw an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: If the first test is wrong, does it fail? Also, is that your actual code, or the code from the tutorial?

Comment: What's the name of your test file? By default, Django will discover tests in any file named “test*.py” under the current working directory.

Comment: I think the class name CategoryMethodTests must begin with Test to be discovered. No idea why you would get one test run otherwise. Try renaming it if you got no better ideas.

Comment: @firelynx, the class name **does not** have to begin with "test". The class methods, however, **do**.

Comment: try putting self.assertTrue(False) in one and self.assertFalse(True) in the other - to see which one isn't running

Comment: @rnevius It does fail if when the first test should. Oh and by the way it's the code from the tutorial.

Comment: @dukebody my test file is named tests.py